# Eloquent Javascript: Chapter 4. Extracting a two-by-two table

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

For the following line of code, why is it necessary that JOURNAL be capitalized in the second to last line when calling the function tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL)?

```
function hasEvent(event, entry) {
  return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1;
}

function tableFor(event, journal) {
  var table = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
    var entry = journal[i], index = 0;
    if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1;
    if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
    table[index] += 1;
  }
  return table;
}

console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL));
// → [76, 9, 4, 1]
```

When I switch JOURNAL to journal, it produces all 0s. I believe it has something to do with the fact that the parameter itself is also called journal, but in lowercase.

When trying to follow the best format for coding, would the better approach be to rename the parameter or variable such that they do not share the same name? For example, would it be a better practice to just rename the "JOURNAL" variable to jacquesJournal?

***EDIT: To answer your questions, the original variable for journal is not listed in the code. However, it is previously mentioned earlier in the chapter with the following line of code:

```
var journal = [];

function addEntry(events, didITurnIntoASquirrel) {
  journal.push({
    events: events,
    squirrel: didITurnIntoASquirrel
  });
}
```

Based on the above line of code, I would imagine that journal would be all lowercase? Should I just assume that for the original line of code (prior to my edit) the journal used in the second to last line was declared with uppercase characters?

Comment: can you provide the values for journal variable? It should not matter

Comment: Well, it should matter. The lowercase journal is the name of the parameter passed into the tableFor function. The uppercase JOURNAL is a variable declared outside of the code posted here, it seems.

Comment: What are the values of `JOURNAL` and `journal`?

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested best approach would be the way I would go. As I commented, the uppercase JOURNAL is a variable declared outside of the code you posted, and the lowercase journal is a placeholder for the parameter passed into the function. An example:

```
var num = 10;

var multiple = function (randomNum) {
    return randomNum * 2;
}

multiple(num); //>> would work as expected but throw an error of undefined if I passed in NUM instead
```

I would imagine, looking at your code that the result would always be 0's for lowercase journal as that variable is undefined.